# Middleman permalink end with slash error

Tags: ruby, middleman

I use Middleman for blogging with `Gemfile`

```
gem "middleman", "~> 3.3.6"
gem "middleman-blog", "~> 3.5.3"
```

I want to config Middleman permalink end with slash.

My configuration `config.rb`

```
activate :blog do |blog|
    blog.permalink = "{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}/"
    blog.default_extension = ".markdown"
end
```

When I run command `middleman` or `middleman server`, It work perfect! I can link to `localhost:4567/2014/11/03/my-article/`

The problem is when I create `middleman build` and try to run command on build folder

`python3 -m http.server 9999`

when link to article, `error file not found,  404 - Nothing matches the given URI.` but file already exist when I open folder

[image]

How to matches URI end with slash instead of file extension (.html)?

**Note:**  If I config permalink end with `.html`, It's OK.

```
activate :blog do |blog|
    blog.permalink = "{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}.html"
    blog.default_extension = ".markdown"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory you need to enable active [directory_indexes](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/pretty-urls/) if you want to have Pretty URLs.

Try

```
activate :blog do |blog|
    blog.permalink = "{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}/"
    blog.default_extension = ".markdown"
end
activate :directory_indexes
```

If that doesn't work try putting the `{title}.html` back in permalink

Comment: Oh my fault, It works! but I put `activate :directory_indexes` before `activate :blog` block and doesn't work, I change to put after `:blog` block  and change `blog.permalink = "{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}"` (If has slash it'll double slash at the end). Thank you so much.